# How to limit ngrx store dependency to Module federated standalone UIs and not part of shell UI

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-module-federation

We have a use case where we are combining different module federated components on a single shell UI. The MFcs are part of standalone UIs that have their own larger business logic context. However, the components that are module federated share some states and therefore the ngrx store is used in one of the standalone UIs.

Now when we move to shell UI none of the other standalone UIs except one uses ngrx store currently. Therefore, it does not feel nice to have ngrx store forRoot initilaization in the shell UI and ngrx specific configs shared via webpack config between shell and standalone UIs (I assume we have to then also share ngrx on those standalone UIs that do not use ngrx store at all for now, but i have not tested this).

My question is if there is an alternative way to not enforce ngrx dependency on the shell UI as shell UI simply displays the module federated components from different standalone UIs and has no interdependencies. The suggestion given [here](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/11) works but I am looking for some alternative solutions to not have this hard dependency on ngrx store in the shell UI.

So far what I have tried is to keep

1. Store.forRoot({}) in the shell UI.
2. Share ngrx store/effects via webpack config between standalone UI and shell UI
3. use store forFeature in module federated components on standalone UI.

Above steps work, but like I said I could not find a way to not have ngrx store dependencies in shell UI especially when shell does not care about any state management between different module federated components.

Also updating the link to same discussion on ngrx store github [issues](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3700#issuecomment-1728712071)

Thanks